# iOS load an image based on user input

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4

fairly new to Objective-C and iOS development (coming from PHP) and I have a relatively simple question that I can't seem to find an answer to:

I am following along with an example for split View design where a web page is loaded into the Detail View when a user clicks an item in the master view. I got all this working, but would like to substitute web view for an image. So I've amended the app to load a UIImage instead of a WebView. What I'm looking for is the equivalent to this code:

```
NSString *urlString = [pagesAddress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

// these 2 is where I get lost with the images.
NSURLRequest = *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[detailViewController.webView loadRequest:request];
```

I came up with this:

```
NSString *imageName = [pagesAddress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

// missing the last 2 calls: one to tell Xcode that it's an image "request" I want and the second to load the actual image (based on it's name that is already in an array) into the ImageView.
```

Thanks.

PS

I tried this:

```
NSString *imageName = [pagesAddress objectAtIndex:indexPath .row];
[detailViewController.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
```

And it shows just the first image, then crashes when I try to show the last one.

Comment: Are you loading the images from an external source or are they local data on the device? (Also you need a UIImageView to replace the WebView, the UIImage is just an instance of the image but not the view)

Comment: yes, I got that part, I replaced the web view with the UIImage view. The images are part of the project, residing in the Supporting files folder.

Comment: What is the crash when you load the last image? Is it an index out of bounds for the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the solution were those 2 lines when I amended the code:

```
NSString *imageName = [pagesAddress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[detailViewController.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
```

Notice that I had to change the setImage to convert the NSString to a UIImage or Xcode would complain. It turns out it was crashing because in the array where I had the image names, I had put 3 images into one entry (basically I forgot the commas!) so it was out of range.

Tim:

This line you gave me

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

is unnecessary because I already have a view created, it would create another view which I never used. Also, replacing it with CGRect seems overkill if I already have a UIImage placeholder no?

In any case, it works now and I'm very grateful for all the help. iPad development with Objectve-C is a very thorny road and I expect I'll be bugging you guys some more.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithConentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
// don't know if you already got the following?
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[imageView setImage:myImage];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

The first line is synchronous (= blocking), so in production, you should rather use `- [NSURLRequest start]` for this (but that's a bit more complicated).

---

Or use this for your local images:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
// Now, follow the same steps as in the first code-example, just skip the first line.
```

Comment: So I would still use a URL for an image? I've changed the view from WebView to UIImageView thinking it would give better performance since it only had to render the image and not the whole URL thing?

Comment: Oh, right, that's correct. I thought you were trying to present an external image (from an URL). I'll update my code now :) ...

Comment: This code you gave me replaces the contents of the main view (the one containing the page names) with the image. I actually need the image to load in the details View. Replacing self.view with detailViewController doesn't work and crashes the app. I had it working with the code above, but it only shows the first image and also crashes.

Comment: Replace `detailViewController` (or `self.view`) with `detailViewController.view`.

Comment: I did and it displays a very small view (the size of the popup where the page names are instead of the big detail view. And also crashes when trying to select another page other than the first one:

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]  initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    [detailViewController.view addSubview:imageView];

Comment: Well, just replace `self.view.bounds` by your `CGRect`, or try replacing it by `detailViewController.view.bounds`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (on iOS 4.0 and later):

```
// Execute a block of code on a background thread.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
               ^(void) 
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    // When IO is done and image created, set it on the main thread.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
                   ^(void) 
    {
        imageView.image = image;
    });
    [pool release];
});
```

Comment: He wants to load a local image, not an external.